# trying to fill state array with objects

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm using axios in order to fetch some objects, i.e:

```
zarusd:cur: Object
usdzar:cur: Object
zartry:cur: Object
tryzar:cur: Object
zarsek:cur: Object
sekzar:cur: Object
zarrub:cur: Object
```

I'm setting my state property to be an array like so:

```
this.state = {
    currecnyData: [],
};
```

But when I console.log typeof after making the request I get an object. How can I make the state property currecnyData an array hosting each object as an array item so I can use a map method on it?
This is my axios call (without the 'options' parameters):

```
axios
    .request(options)
    .then((response) => {
        this.setState(
            {
                currecnyData: [response.data.result],
            },
            () => {
                console.log(typeof this.state.currecnyData);
            }
        );
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

Comment: can you provide the `response.data` here ?

Comment: That's what `typeof` returns for Arrays. You can use `Array.isArray` function instead to make that check.

Comment: @tedd Thanks, the objects I mentioned at the top of the post are my response.data

Answer (score 0):

```
this.setState(
          {
            currecnyData: Object.entries(response.data.result),
          }
```

`Object.entries` solved my issue! Now I get an array of all the objects.

Answer (score 0):

Object.entries will convert object into an array as you wanted it to be

```
axios.request(options)
  .then((response) => {
    this.setState(
      {
        currecnyData: Object.entries(response.data.result); ,
      },
          () => {

            console.log(typeof this.state.currecnyData);
          }
    );
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.error(error);
  });
```